# How do I add more than 4 arguments to a function in MIPS?

Tags: c++, assembly, mips, calling-convention, mips32

Okay, so I am to translate this C++ code

> funcArr2(12, a2, a3, a4, used1, used2, &used3, &used4);

and I have so far been able to translate the a1-a4 with

```
        li $a0, 12
        addi $a1, $sp, 280
        addi $a2, $sp, 328
        addi $a3, $sp, 376
        **missing code for arguments 5-8**
        jal funcArr2
```

However, I'm completely at a loss on how to continue adding the other arguments, I remember vaguely having to save it on the stack however I don't remember the code to do that.

Comment: Check how the C++ compiler on your platform does it by looking at asm output for a simple function that calls the function you want with constant args.  Like https://godbolt.org/g/ayZAG4.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180417-00/?p=98525) has been blogging about this recently (for NT at least), and covers the subject in some detail.

In some MIPS calling conventions, at least Linux and NT, functions always get 16 bytes of "home space" on the stack, even if they accept fewer than 4 register args.  The 5th and later integer arg goes above that, on the stack.

Comment: To those who voted to edit my post, please explain how these edits were in any way an improvement.  Changing 'in luck' to 'lucky' is clearly not idiomatic, and 'click here' links are widely deprecated on the net.  Thank you.

Comment: That's an excellent link, but link-only answers are not ok on Stack Overflow.  The answer needs to stand on its own even if the link dies, so extract / summarize at least some key parts of it.

Comment: It won't die.  the Old New Thing has been going for years.  Anyway, you have already summarised it for me.

Comment: It's still a link-only answer, and should just be a comment if you didn't want to write an actual answer.  [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231) and [Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505)

Comment: It's more than just a link.  It says what you will find at the end of the link, and tells you that the blogger is Raymond Chen, who is widely respected.  Surely that's enough.

Comment: You're still misunderstanding the point.  Even if the right answer to e.g. a Java question was found on a page of official Java documentation about a standard library class / function, Stack Overflow standards/policy requires an actual summary of the answer at least, e.g. `Math.floor` provides the IEEE floor function in Java", not "look here for the right function".

Comment: Fixed your answer for you.  See: not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

The other arguments are passed on the stack:

The memory at `$sp+16` contains the 5th argument, the memory at `$sp+20` contains the 6th argument and so on...

**Example:**

```
; myFunction(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

addiu $sp, $sp, -28
...
li $a0, 5
sw $a0, 16($sp)
li $a0, 6
sw $a0, 20($sp)
li $a0, 7
sw $a0, 24($sp)
li $a0, 1
li $a1, 2
li $a2, 3
li $a3, 4
jal myFunction
```

**Important:**

A C/C++ function having at least one argument is allowed to overwrite the memory at `$sp+0`. A C/C++ function having at least two arguments is allowed to overwrite the memory at `$sp+4` and so on...

So if you "simply" call a function with **two** arguments the following way:

```
li $a0, 12
li $a1, 34
jal someFunction
```

... it may be that the function will overwrite the stack locations `$sp+0`...`$sp+7`.

So even when calling a function with only two arguments you have to ensure that these stack locations may be overwritten:

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -8
...
li $a0, 12
li $a1, 34
jal someFunction
```

Comment: Which MIPS calling convention are you describing, exactly?  Raymond Chen's link (in Paul's answer) says that the Windows NT on MIPS convention reserves "home space" on the stack for the register args (even if there are fewer than 4), like the Windows x64 convention.  But your answer says the "home space" size depends on the number of args.  That doesn't look like that gcc for Linux MIPS does: https://godbolt.org/g/ayZAG4 uses `addiu $sp, $sp, -32` for a function that calls a one-arg function.  (I guess keeping SP aligned, and leaving room for home space + spill slot for link register.)

Comment: gcc for MIPS doesn't support `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`; that's an x86 option only, so I can't check my guess that it's keeping the stack aligned.

Comment: @PeterCordes I simplified my answer a lot. Sorry for that. What I wanted to point out is the existence of a "home space" at all. The user seems not to be aware of such a home space at all.

Comment: You simplified it wrong, though.  A C/C++ function having at least one (or even zero?) argument(s) is still allowed to clobber `sp+0..15`, not just `sp+0..3`.  Unless you can cite official docs saying that the home-space is variable size, evidence from compiler output for Linux and Raymond Chen's blog for NT says disagrees with your answer on this critical point which could easily lead to subtle hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: My understanding is that the called function can use the home space (all 16 bytes of it) for whatever it wants.  Unoptimised code should spill any parameters passed in via registers there though so that you can inspect them in the debugger.  As Raymond's blog points out, things get interesting when passing floating point parameters  and when calling variadic functions, especially if the function is not prototyped.  And, he tells us, things vary by platform. This question is more complex than it looks!